# ActiveAdmin error 401 Can no longer log in with working credentials. Using rails 5.2

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I created an ActiveAdmin user and I can no longer log on using any of my previous ActiveAdmin users nor can I create a new one. When I try, I get a 401 error. I have tried multiple times to manipulate the devise initializer and the model to no avail.
Using rails 5.2.1,activeadmin 1.3.1, activeadmin_addons 1.6.0, cancancan 2.2.0
active_admin_role 0.2.1

> Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Xyn9lV8tJQE9+Kii+LjFwiwrR4VKOXF8oACcQK4ui8Nb/9jkqDY8hfCHKEpX4/ftO3aKtdb0KJ9RXTq1TIbhpw==", "admin_user"=>{"login"=>"hodari@hiddengeniusproject.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
>     AdminUser Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE (lower(email) = 'hodari@hiddengeniusproject.org') ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
>   Completed 401 Unauthorized in 149ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)

Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",

"authenticity_token"=>"Xyn9lV8tJQE9+Kii+LjFwiwrR4VKOXF8oACcQK4ui8Nb/9jkqDY8hfCHKEp   X4/ftO3aKtdb0KJ9RXTq1TIbhpw==", "admin_user"=>{"login"=>" ", "password"=>" 
  [FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Rendering /Users/professortoure/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activeadmin- 
  1.3.1/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within 
  layouts/active_admin_logged_out
  Rendered /Users/professortoure/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activeadmin- 
  1.3.1/app/views/active_admin/devise/shared/_links.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/professortoure/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activeadmin- 
  1.3.1/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within 
  layouts/active_admin_logged_out (51.6ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 838ms (Views: 836.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Here is my adminuser model

class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
    role_based_authorizable
    devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
       attr_accessor :login
       has_many :classrooms
       protected

```
   def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
     conditions = warden_conditions.dup
     login = conditions.delete(:login)
     where(conditions).where(["lower(email) = :value", { :value => login 
}]).first
   end
 end
```

and here is my devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|

config.secret_key = ENV['devise_secret_key'] if Rails.env.production?
config.mailer_sender = 'Devise Omniauth  
config.mailer = 'Devise::Mailer'
config.parent_mailer = 'ActionMailer::Base'

config.authentication_keys = [:login]
config.reset_password_keys = [:login]

config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email, :username ]
config.params_authenticatable = true
config.http_authenticatable = false
config.paranoid = true
config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true
config.reload_routes = true
config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11

config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 364.days
config.confirm_within = 365.daysconfig.reconfirmable = true
config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
config.password_length = 6..128
config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
config.unlock_strategy = :both
config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

Rails.application.config.app_middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
 config.omniauth :google_oauth2,
 Figaro.env.google_client_id,
 Figaro.env.google_client_secret
 #google_oauth2_options
  {
    scope: 'email, calendar',
    prompt: 'select_account',
    image_aspect_ratio: 'original',
    name: 'google',
    access_type: 'offline',
    provider_ignores_state: true
  } 
end
end
```

I'm am not sure what else to include, I am still learning.

thank you

Comment: are you able to post a minimum code sample on Github?

Comment: also `Figaro.env.google_client_id` you have to accordingly post the key and value pairs - where is the key for this value?

Comment: Hi @BKSpurgeon thank you for your clarifying questions, I created a sample branch =>https://github.com/quietwar/HgpApp/tree/sample. I am not using google auth right now so, i just commented it out. Please let me know if you need anything else as I really appreciate the help.

Comment: is it solved? pls confirm

Comment: Hi @BKSpurgeon, no I had to step away from it because i was stuck. Were you able to look at the repository?

Comment: I was going to, but wanted to first check if you were serious about this project - because it does take a lot of time and effort delving into these things......

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Oh, I see, no I am extremely serious about this. I am trying to make this an app to communicate with our students. But i am running into issues because of my lack of experience.

Comment: aight i've cloned the repo and will have a closer look at lunchtime (my timezone) - can't guarantee a solution though. guess we'll find out in a few hours

Comment: btw you've checked your secrets into the repo (which you should never ever do). it's ok though. nobody cares. but i have to ask: are you comfortable with me using those secrets or shall i just create my own?

Comment: yeah, at this point, i am total ok with that, there is no data in the databases other than my generic sign in. But thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Firstly there's a problem with this migration: `20180716205753 AddRoleToAdminUser` - fix it up here. you first need the admin users table - my migrations aren't running. secondly you're not at all following rails conventions. the migration should be `AddRoleToAdminUsers` (PLURAL)

Comment: i've given it a good shot..........i think it's as far as i can go - best of wishes.

Comment: follow rails conventions as best you can it will make it easy for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went back into my git repository to the last known working version and reset to there. Not sure what the problem was but my app is working again.